# Definition of 'completeness' of a valued field

Tags: field-theory, definition, complete-spaces, valuation-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

I have on a number of occasions seen reference to 'complete valued fields' without any explanation of precisely what completeness means in this context. It is definitely not referring to maximal completeness or spherical completeness, but rather something along the lines of Cauchy completeness. Although most of the literature refers to complete **discrete** valued fields, some of it appears to indicate that completeness also works in a non-discrete setting.

Most importantly, I need to understand the notion of completeness referred to in Proposition 6 of [this paper](http://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/amsval.pdf), where it is claimed that completeness follows from maximal completeness. I add the definition of a valued field that I am working with below to avoid confusion:

A *valued field* is a field $K$ equipped with a *valuation*, which is a **surjective** map $v:K\to G\cup\lbrace\infty\rbrace$ where $v(x)=\infty\Leftrightarrow x=0$ and $$v(xy)=v(x)+v(y),$$ $$v(x+y)\geq\min\lbrace v(x),v(y)\rbrace$$ for all $x,y\in K$ and where $G$ is a totally ordered abelian group, called its *value group*.

Is there a common understanding of what 'completeness' means in the context of valued fields?

Comment: One can characterize completeness for a valued field $(K,v)$ as it having no proper dense (valued field) extension. Since any dense extension is immediate, maximality entails completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are definitely referring to Cauchy completeness, i.e. the assertion that every Cauchy [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) converges (you could also use [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)) if you prefer; note it is important to use nets/filters in lieu of sequences because the space may not be first countable). For $g\in G$ one can define the subset $U_g:=\{x\in K\mid v(x)>g\}$, and then there is a unique topology on $K$ for which $\{U_g\mid g\in G\}$ is a neighborhood basis of $0$, and this topology makes $K$ into a topological field. For any topological abelian group the following notions make sense (note: you probably don't actually need the word "abelian" here):

> **Definition**: If $A$ is a topological abelian group, then a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ is *Cauchy* if for every neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there exists some $i_0\in I$ such that $x_i-x_j\in U$ for all $i,j\ge i_0$.

> **Definition**: A net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ *converges* to $x\in A$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists some $i_0\in I$ such that $x_i\in U$ for all $i\ge i_0$.

> **Definition**: A topological abelian group is *complete* if every Cauchy net converges.

Just in case you want full assurance this is what the author means, here is the source they are citing in case you have not been able to look at it, you can see they are talking about Cauchy filters in the first sentence of the proof:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'm familiar with using nets but not so much with filters. Am I right in thinking that both approaches are essentially equivalent i.e. statements about nets can be translated into statements about filters and vice versa?

Comment: @thewonderfulwizardofoz yes definitely.